# How to fix 'avr-g++: error: device-specs/specs-atmega328p: No such file or directory' error in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide

I am programming my arduino uno on the new raspberry pi 4. I have installed arduino IDE v1.8.9 and I am having issues in compiling the code.

I am getting an error.

avr-g++: error: device-specs/specs-atmega328p: No such file or directory

Please Help.

I am running Rasbian Os

```
/*
  AnalogReadSerial

  Reads an analog input on pin 0, prints the result to the Serial Monitor.
  Graphical representation is available using Serial Plotter (Tools > Serial Plotter menu).
  Attach the center pin of a potentiometer to pin A0, and the outside pins to +5V and ground.

  This example code is in the public domain.

  http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogReadSerial
*/

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(1);        // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the -tools option for arduino-builder missing the location avr. 
A setting like

-tools /home/owner/arduino-1.8.10/hardware/tools/avr

is needed so as to find the spec files. Set your compile output to verbose to see the compile command that is issued, and verify above line is present.

More info: https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder/issues/263